Why does Google show a movie scene as a song?
Google.com lists the famous "Are you talking to me?" scene from Taxi Driver
(1976) as a song, and credits Robert De Niro as the artist:

Why does Google show a movie scene as a song?

Because the video is simply incorrectly indentified, not sure about the purpose of this question.
